# Как сделать чтобы все было по середине

Tags: html, css

Мне надо чтобы надписи внутри блока оказались по центру (`text-align: center;`) и по центру высоты, например (`justify-content: center;`). Как это сделать? Я пытался сделать всеми возможными способами но либо криво высота вставала либо какие то проблемы были. Помогите пожалуйста

```
<div class="block-1">
    <div class="blue"><h1 class="block-1-text">ФАЙЛЫ</h1></div>
</div>
```

```
.block-1 {
    background: #191f36!important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.block-1-text {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь вам так надо :)

```css
.block-1 {
  background: #191f36!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block-1-text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="blue">
    <h1 class="block-1-text">ФАЙЛЫ</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикинь, я так же делал и не помогало как всегда

А тут ты скинул код и заработало, понимаю ахахах